# Is my proof that $R$ unique factorization domain $\implies$ $R[X]$ unique factorization domain correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I myself  want to prove the fundamental fact that is:

> If $R$ is UFD then so is $R[X]$.

Here is my approach:

Let $f$ is a polynomial of $R[X]$ and assume $\deg(f)=d$,  $d$ is non-negative integer.

We just consider the case $f$ is not irreducible then we have the factorization:
$f$= $d_1d_2...d_m.f_1.f_2...f_n...$.

Where $d_i $ is an irreducible element of $R$ and $f_i$ is a polynomial which have degree at least $1$.

Because the degree of $f$ is $d$ is finite and each $f_i$ has degree at least $1$ so we can not have infinite those elements $f_i$.

Now,  if  we have two factorizations $f$=$f_1.f_2...f_n$ = $g_1.g_2...g_m$ $(1)$ so:

$g_1| f_1.f_2...f_n$ we must have some $f_i$, say $f_1$ such that: $g_1|f_1$ 
by the irreducibility of $f_1$ we conclude $f_1$= $a_1$.$g_1$, where $a_1$ is unit in $R$.  Cancel both  $f_1$ and $g_1$ from $(1)$ and continue on this fashion we have $m \le n$.

Conversely, $f_1|g_1...g_n$,   use the same argument  we also have $n\le m$ then $n=m$.

This proof is the first pop in to my head, I also red the popular proof for the theorem in textbook.  I would say my process is wrong at certain point, but I cant see it. Please illustrate the point to me. Thank you.

Comment: You are using that $\,g_i\,$ irreducible $\,\Rightarrow\, g_i\,$ prime but you haven't proved that. You also need to prove the uniqueness of the constant factors $\,d_i.\ $

Comment: Are you willing to assume the result for $R$ a field?